# How to use TelephonyCallback.CellInfoListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, listener, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I'd like to get cell information updates on an android 12 phone.
I can do this for older versions of android using *PhoneStateListener* class and *listen* method. But they are deprecated in android 12.
I'v tried below code but it doesn't show cellInfo.

```
val tm: TelephonyManager = this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
     tm.registerTelephonyCallback(this.mainExecutor, object:TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CellInfoListener{
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                override fun onCellInfoChanged (cellInfo:List<CellInfo>) {
                    testTextView?.text = cellInfo.toString()   }  }    )
        } else { 
             var psListener= MyPhoneStateListener(tm)
             tm.listen(psListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS) }
```

Does any one know what I should do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [The documentation for `listen()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#listen) points you [to `registerTelephonyCallback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#registertelephonycallback) for use on API Level 31+ devices.

Comment: I have read it and I have used it. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Executor executorist= new Executor() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }
};
class CellInfoListener extends TelephonyCallback
        implements TelephonyCallback.CellInfoListener {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCellInfoChanged(@NonNull List<CellInfo> list) {
        //FooFighters will do it, but your own function could do it too
        FooFighters(list);
    }
}
CellInfoListener cellists= new CellInfoListener();
tmanager.registerTelephonyCallback(executorist,cellists);
```

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r33:cts/tests/tests/telephony/current/src/android/telephony/cts/